# Closing multiple hidden forms - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, hidden

I Have a Main Form and 3 other forms in my application and the procedure the program follows is as follows :

1.) On the main form the user clicks on the a button which launches another where he can choose a date(s)

2.)Then another form launches where he chooses a a time slot and a bunch of other things

3.)Finally the third form is launched and here the user manages a session he has chosen in the previous forms. If the user is done there, he presses back which brings the previous form (Choose time slot etc.. form) and then he can choose another  time slot and the third form is shown again and so on.

4.) if the user is done he can go back two forms and choose another date, or go back 3 forms to the Main Form (Also the main menu).

However if the User wants to go back the main form directly from the third form how would go about doing that? how do i close the other 2 open forms that are only hidden, not closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a button on each of the forms that calls a `Close()` method on each of the forms.

```
private void btn_Finish(args...)
{
    form1.CloseAll();
    form2.CloseAll();
    form3.CloseAll();
    // Only if the main form is closed/Invisible
    MainForm.Show()
    // OR
    MainForm.Visible = true;
}
```

And on each form:

```
public static void CloseAll();
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: actually you won't need `form1.CloseAll();` on `form1` that will just be `CloseAll`. Same for all the others as well.

Comment: "static" and "this" ??